# vsts release dotnet core on Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-devops, release

I'm trying to deploy a dotnet core application on a Linux server (CentOS)

I'm currently using a Command Line Script, but the script will never end because the application keeps running

What is the appropriate method of running a dotnet core application on Linux from a vsts agent?

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that you have read this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying .net core app to Linux, you need to configure your ASP.NET Core Site With Nginx, then deploying the .net core app to Linux.

For detail configurations, you can refer the document [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) (as harmoniemand mentions). Or you can refer the blogs [Hosting .Net Core On Linux](https://www.tonyranieri.com/blog/2017/10/27/Hosting-.Net-Core-On-Linux/) and [Deploying .NET Core To Linux](https://www.tonyranieri.com/blog/2017/12/01/Deploying-.NET-Core-To-Linux/).